# implementing docusign connect api

Tags: docusignapi, webhooks

Since connect api sends the response to the "listner api" IMMEDIETELY after the last recipient signs the document. If my "listner api" is down at that perticular time. How will I get the response again from connect api?
Does connect api provide any option to send it again?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the option to **Require Acknowledgement**. As per the documentation:

> Require Acknowledgement: Select this option to log posting failures.
>   The acknowledgement failure messages are logged in the Failures page,
>   which is accessed b clicking Failures on the DocuSign Connect Settings
>   page. When this option is selected, DocuSign will automatically
>   attempt to repost any failures. Alternately, you can manually repost
>   from the Failures page. See the Publish Failures section for more
>   information

As long as your application can return a 200 status code when it does successfully accept a Connect publish, having Require Acknowledgement on means that failures will be logged and retried.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Drew is correct, but here's some additional information: the Connect resend algorithm, used if require acknowledgement is on, does not try to resend immediately. And if the Connect Send Individual Messages (SIM) option is off (the default), then a message won't be resent if the message is superseded by another message about the same envelope.

Better is to not have your server (your "listener") ever go down. Best way to do that: have Connect send to AWS or similar, then your app pulls from AWS SQS or similar. See the code examples named `connect-` here: https://github.com/docusign